# AWS Cloudfront 503 "FunctionThrottledError" when using Cloudfront function for URL rewriting

Tags: amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, terraform, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

We have a Single Page Application (TypeScript/JS) hosted on a AWS S3 bucket, served with a Cloudfront distribution.

Requesting the base URL of the Cloudfront distribution returns the application (for instance: `https://cloudfront-distribution-base-url.com/`). The path appended to the URL is only handled by the frontend app (JS router) and does not match with a resource on the S3 bucket (for instance: `https://cloudfront-distribution-base-url.com/some-path`).

However, when the client goes back on the previous page (by clicking on "previous" button of the browser for instance), then the browser requests the previous URL, including its full path. This does not match any resource on the S3 bucket, resulting into an "Object not found" error.

In order to prevent "Object not found" error, we want to remove the path part of the request URL made to the cloudfront distribution. In other words, we want to have a URL rewrite rule on our cloudrfront distribution that rewrites `https://cloudfront-distribution-base-url.com/some-path` into `https://cloudfront-distribution-base-url.com/`.

To achieve this, we have attached a Cloudfront function to our Cloudfront distribution. This JS function simply remove the path part of the requested URL.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "our_spa_distribution" {
                          
    function_association {                                                        
      event_type   = "viewer-request"    
      function_arn = aws_cloudfront_function.our_spa.arn
    }  

    ...                                                   
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_function" "our_spa" {
  runtime = "cloudfront-js-1.0"
  publish = true
  code    = file("${path.module}/url_rewrite.js")

  ...
}
```

The function code content simply removes the path part:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.request;
    request.uri = '/';
    return callback(null, request);
}
```

Using this configuration, we get a `503 The request could not satisfied` error from Cloudfront. Note the response `X-Cache` header contains `FunctionThrottledError from cloudfront`. The function is never executed, so no logs are logged by Cloudwatch into the logs groups as mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-logs.html#cloudfront-function-logs.

It might be a quota issue, however, we do not have any traffic on that distribution, and the default quota are more than enough for the few requests we made (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-functions).

What could be the reason for that 503 error ? Also, perhaps we are considering the wrong solution to serve our single-page application; is there any better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your cloudfront function code

it should be

```js
function handler(event) {
    event.request.uri = '/index.html'
    return event.request;
}
```

but as you're saying it's a single page app, it's very likely that you don't have just a index.html so be careful as here **all url** will be rewritten as  `/`  (for example "main.css" will be rewritten which will break your app)

you may want to do something like this

```js
function handler(event) {
    // only rewrite path that are handled by your javascript framework routing
    // and leave the other resources (.css / .js / .png etc.) as it
    if (is_path_handled_by_spa(event.request.uri)) {
       event.request.uri = '/index.html';
    }
    return event.request;
}
```